# Error handling and saving logs to text files

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling

I want to do error handling in javascript.

I want to log the error occurred in the javascript.

I don't want to use the database to store the errors.I want to store all the error in a txt file(that txt file should be present in the server where that website is hosted. So that others can't access that file.

How to do the above requirement.

I searched in Google and find

```
function WriteToFile() {
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\Test.txt", true);
s.WriteLine('Hello');
s.Close();
}
```

this is also not working in all conditions.

**1. You're using a non-ie browser (which doesn't support activex objects)**

**2. you're using an ie browser on an xp machine with sp2 installed and the activex object is being blocked**

So please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you've found is for client-side files, so wouldn't work for your purpose even if all browsers supported it. You could make an Ajax request to the server and use server-side code to write the data to a file...

Comment: Use `XMLHttpRequest` to send messages to a servlet running on your host that stores the log lines in a database or file there.

Comment: Where is the Javascript executed, in a browser? Where do you want to store the error log? Please notice that arbitrary websites are not allowed by the browser to write files on the local disk.

Comment: Means i can't log errors through javascript without using server side ajax call :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI you can use alternative way to handle the error as below code

```
jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "urlpage",
      dataType: "html",
      data: "types":$("#catid").val(),
      success: function (response) {
              alert("Successfully!!!");
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
    });
```

When any error occurred you can call another ajax function or same function once again.

This works mostly in all ajax call to handle error, Try it.

Comment: I am using a html page so i don't have any code behind. So i can't use ajax there to call a webmethod.Is there any way to log the error in a txt file using javascript

Answer (score 1):

Use a try/catch to detect the error first of all:

```
try
{
    // code that could error here
}
catch(err)
{
    // do an ajax call to the server
}
```

In the `catch` block, you could do an ajax call to the server. On the server you will need some server side script (such as PHP, ASP etc etc) to process the request and log the error to a local text file. In the catch block above, `err.message` will give you the error message string which you can include in your ajax call.

Comment: I am using a html page so i don't have any code behind. So i can't use ajax there to call a webmethod.Is there any way to log the error in a txt file using javascript